# Generic function for multiple arrays of same datatypes in c?

Tags: c, arrays, generics

I want to have a generic function that can operates on multiple arrays of different size but same datatypes and takes array number only as an argument. Let's consider three arrays `arr1[10]`, `arr2[15]`, `arr3[20]`. The generic function should be like:

```
void func(int array_number)
{
   for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
   {
     arrz[i] = i;
   }
}
```

Here array size `y` will be selected based on `array_number` (argument) and `z` in `arrz[i]` should be the `array_number` (argument of `func`) so that `func` puts data in respective array. Is it possible in c language?
I know one solution is to send some number as argument during function call for diffrentiating arrays but I actually do not want to use if-else in `func` to avoid lengthy code.

Comment: Have two arguments: One is the array itself (a pointer to the first element), and the second is the size (in number of elements) of the array.

Comment: It sounds like you have a poor design and seek ways to make it worse... What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you have variables with horrible names such as `name1, name2, name3`? Make an array of arrays or an array of structs instead. And what are those variables, globals? Smells very fishy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will need to know about each array and select one based on the number.  If you have a small fixed number of global arrays as in your example, you can use `switch` to select one:

```
void func(int array_number)
{
    int *arr;
    int len, i;

    switch (array_number) {
    case 1:
       arr = arr1;
       len = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
       break;
    case 2:
       arr = arr2;
       len = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]);
       break;
    case 3:
       arr = arr3;
       len = sizeof(arr3) / sizeof(arr3[0]);
       break;
    default:
       return;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Of course, the most flexible thing to do is to change the function to take the array (a pointer to the first element technically) and the length.

```
void func(int *arr, int len)
{
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a helper function that accepts `int *` and `size_t` to do the incremental assignments.

```
void func_helper(int *arr, size_t length) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int) i;
  }
}
```

... and another function to translate the index into a the array pointer and length.

No use of a long chain of `if-else` statements

```
int arr1[10], arr2[15], arr3[20];

void func(int array_index) {
  const struct xx {
    int *ptr;
    size_t length;
  } arrays[] = { //
      { arr1, sizeof arr1 / sizeof arr1[0] }, //
      { arr2, sizeof arr2 / sizeof arr2[0] }, //
      { arr3, sizeof arr3 / sizeof arr3[0] } };
  const size_t n = sizeof arrays / sizeof arrays[0];

  // Test array_index validity
  if (array_index > 0 && array_index <= n) {
    array_index--;
    func_helper(arrays[array_index].ptr, arrays[array_index].length);
  }
}
```